# Will Project Loom Virtual Threads improve the perfomance of parallel Streams?

Tags: java, project-loom

This is not a duplicate of [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

The question goes to the heart of Project Loom design and implementation, and whether the project has been able to speed up the performance of Java Parallel Streams or not. The question is not about bench-marking, it is about intent of Project Loom.

---

I am experimenting with Virtual Threads in my [loom-lab](https://github.com/kolotyluk/loom-lab) project, and wanted to see if Virtual Threads are faster than Platform Threads when doing a parallel stream, but it actually seems slower.

```
try (var executorService = Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor(virtualThreadFactory)) {
    var candidates3 = LongStream.iterate(3, x -> x < count, x -> x + 2);
    time4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    var primes3 = executorService.submit(() ->
        candidates3.parallel()
            .filter(candidate -> isPrime(candidate)).toArray()
    ).get();
    time5 = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

where ultimately I get the output (in milliseconds)

```
sequential time = 7546
parallel   time = 1289
virtual    time = 1388
```

and in general using Virtual Threads is slower than the common ForkJoinPool. Am I making some basic mistake or misunderstanding somewhere, or has Project Loom not been integrated with Java Streams yet?

Comment: IIUC, the real benefit of a virtual thread is when you have a blocking I/O operation. With Loom, the underlying *carrier thread* will continue executing other tasks while your virtual thread blocks. Before Loom, this distinction was not made - there was only one type of threads - and the blocking I/O was not a feasible option for high throughput applications, like web servers. You might find [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOEPEXTpbJA) helpful.

Comment: This question is 90% similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69830934/6367213). Try to avoid asking the same question twice. You can always edit your questions to dispute the closure.

Comment: I have never had a question closed by someone else before, so I was confused by the process... will checkout the presentation...

Comment: LOOM will allow better scaling for multi-threaded app servers with blocking I/O and simplify coding. Unfortunately some examples of using LOOM virtual threads suggest dramatic performance improvements - that is until you spot that the benchmarks use `Thread.sleep()` in the `Runnable` task so are not real-world cases.

Comment: Do several warmup runs. Your candidates stream `LongStream.iterate(3, x -> x < count, x -> x + 2)` isn't suitable for parallelisation - each value depends on the previous so it must be evaluated sequentially? Perhaps `Arrays.stream(LongStream.iterate(3, x -> x < count, x -> x + 2).toArray())` would be better, so that every input value is pre-computed before your tests begin.

Comment: @DuncG thanks for the `Array` idea, but in testing, it makes no difference. Whoever implemented Java Streams must be pretty smart because it sure seems to do the right thing with so little effort.

Comment: Besides the fact that virtual threads can’t accelerate a CPU bound computation in general, this test is pointless, it incorrectly assumes that the parallel stream will use the `executorService`. The parallel Stream will still use the default ForkJoin pool. The caller thread is the only virtual thread involved.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, my sense of things is that

> IIUC, the real benefit of a virtual thread is when you have a blocking I/O operation. With Loom, the underlying carrier thread will continue executing other tasks while your virtual thread blocks. Before Loom, this distinction was not made - there was only one type of threads - and the blocking I/O was not a feasible option for high throughput applications, like web servers.

means that Virtual Threads are not going to give me the performance boost I was hoping for in this use case...

In my experiment, I was computing prime numbers with

1. 7397 ms - sequential stream
2. 1316 ms - parallel stream
3. 1392 ms - parallel stream in the context of an Execution Service with Virtual Threads
4. 4472 ms - Virtual Threads with `executorService.invokeAll(tasks)`
5. 4338 ms - Virtual Threads created from a Stream

Cases 2 & 3 are so close in performance, they are within the margin of error.

This is not I/O bound, it is purely compute bound. Parallel Streams work exceptionally well in this case, and it's hard (impossible?) to do better. My expectation I could speed things up with Virtual Threads was a misunderstanding of how Virtual Threads are optimized. Now I know better.

If I want to demonstrate the performance advantage of Virtual Threads over Platform Threads, I need to find a better use case.

My code is posted on [loom-lab](https://github.com/kolotyluk/loom-lab) in case other people want to verify my conclusions. This is a learning project, and I am learning...